# XSLT multi-level list depending on category name

Tags: xslt

I want to build a multi level nested list, depending on the category name. This is my xml:

```
<UserDefinedTable xmlns="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable">
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>28</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Category>KatOne</Category>
    <Title>Level 1</Title>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>29</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Category>KatOneSub</Category>
    <Title>Level 2</Title>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>30</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Category>KatOneSub</Category>
    <Title>Level 2</Title>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>31</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Category>KatTwo</Category>
    <Title>Level 1</Title>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>32</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Category>KatTwoSub</Category>
    <Title>Level 2</Title>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <UserDefinedRowId>33</UserDefinedRowId>
    <Category>KatTwoSub</Category>
    <Title>Level 2</Title>
  </Data>
</UserDefinedTable>
```

And this is my attempt at the XSLT template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:udt="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable" exclude-result-prefixes="udt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="prefix_param">udt_<xsl:value-of select="//udt:Context/udt:ModuleId" />_param</xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="udt:Data" mode="list">

    <xsl:for-each select="udt:Data">
    <li>
        <span>KatUpper</span>

        <ul class="level-two">
            <xsl:for-each select="udt:Data">
                <li>
                    KatSub
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>                   

    </li>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/udt:UserDefinedTable">
    <xsl:variable name="currentData" select="udt:Data" />
    <xsl:if test="$currentData">
    <ul class="my-list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="EditLink">
    <xsl:if test="udt:EditLink">
      <a href="{udt:EditLink}">
        <img border="0" alt="edit" src="{//udt:Context/udt:ApplicationPath}/images/edit.gif" />
      </a>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to make a foreach that check if the cateogry name mathces this or that then it stays on upper level, and inside each iteration i would check for category name to have  a nested list inside:

Something like this:

```
<ul class="my-list">
    <li>
        <span>KatOne</span>

        <ul clasS="levelTwo">
            <li>
                KatOneSub
            </li>
            <li>
                KatOneSub
            </li>
            <li>
                KatOneSub
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>KatTwo</span>

        <ul clasS="levelTwo">
            <li>
                KatTwoSub
            </li>
            <li>
                KatTwoSub
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? This would be easier to solve using `xsl:for-each-group` with "group-starting-with". Also, can you have more than 2 levels of nesting? Thanks!

Comment: yes, i am. No, 2 levels will be max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current problem is that within the template matching `udt:Data`, you do `<xsl:for-each select="udt:Data">`, but this will be looking for child elements of the current `Data` element that also called `Data`. You should really be looking for siblings here.

In XSLT 1.0, you could make use of a key to look up the "Level 2" items based on the first preceding "Level 1" items

```
<xsl:key name="level2" 
         match="udt:Data[udt:Title='Level 2']" 
         use="preceding-sibling::udt:Data[udt:Title='Level 1'][1]/udt:UserDefinedRowId" />
```

You would then start off by selecting the "Level 1" items

```
<xsl:variable name="currentData" select="udt:Data[udt:Title='Level 1']" />

<xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list" />
```

Then, to get the "Level 2" items for the current "Level 1" item, you can do use the key

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('level2', udt:UserDefinedRowId)">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:udt="DotNetNuke/UserDefinedTable" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="udt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="level2" 
           match="udt:Data[udt:Title='Level 2']" 
           use="preceding-sibling::udt:Data[udt:Title='Level 1'][1]/udt:UserDefinedRowId" />

  <xsl:template match="udt:Data" mode="list">
    <li>
      <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="udt:Category" />
      </span>
      <xsl:if test="key('level2', udt:UserDefinedRowId)">
        <ul class="levelTwo">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('level2', udt:UserDefinedRowId)">
            <li>
              <span>
                <xsl:value-of select="udt:Category" />
              </span>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/udt:UserDefinedTable">
    <xsl:variable name="currentData" select="udt:Data[udt:Title='Level 1']" />
    <xsl:if test="$currentData">
      <ul class="my-list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentData" mode="list" />
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you should change expressions like `Title="Level 1"` accordingly if you have a better way of identifying Level 1 and Level 2 elements.

Comment: THe first problem i see here is, i cant select/comapre by title, has to use Category every time, just depends wether the category is KatOne, KatTwo, KatThree and sub lists have "sub" added to end, titles will varry, these are test ones

Comment: You really need an unambiguous way to identify what your "level 1" and "level 2" items are, otherwise you will have problems. Do you have any control over the input XML? Adding a `Level` element to each `Data` item would be the simplest solution then.

Comment: i can yes, lets call it "item-level", so we keep same category for level 1 and level 2 and define a new attribute which defines level?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Then the `xsl:for-each-group` becomes `<xsl:for-each-group select="Data" group-starting-with="Data[item-level='1']">` and everything else can stay the same.

Comment: I changed that and it doesnt work for me, in fact i get a compile error that for-each-group can't be nested inside xsl:if

Comment: Can you update your question with your new-improved XML structure, and I will modify my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: And are you sure you can definitely use XSLT 2.0? That error message suggests not...

Comment: should be able to, what would be approach in case i cant?

Comment: You could do it with the use of a key. You can find out for sure, by adding `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` to your XSLT, and seeing what is output.

Comment: so this needs them to have same category and different level value if i understand this correctly?

Comment: They can have any category, but you just need a way to properly identify the levels.